# Printing random numbers in tkinter (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to write program which draws random number from a list after clicking button. I've written it, but it's doesn't work like I would like to. It's printing the numbers one under the other. [It's working like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j51PU.png)

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def draw(param):
    number = Label(root, height=1, width=20, text=param)
    return number.pack()

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=450)
frame.pack()

numbers = [x for x in range(1,6)]

buttonDraw = Button(frame, text="Draw",
                                       command=lambda: draw(random.choice(numbers)))

buttonDraw.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to replace previous first number with new random number after clicking a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're making new `tkinter.Label` each time you press a button. Make a `tkinter.Label` outside of the `draw` method and and only change the value in the `draw` method.

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def draw(param):
    num.set(param)

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=450)
frame.pack()

numbers = [x for x in range(1, 6)]

buttonDraw = Button(frame, text="Draw",
                    command=lambda: draw(random.choice(numbers)))

buttonDraw.pack()
num = StringVar()
Label(root, height=1, width=20, textvariable=num).pack()
root.mainloop()
```